# C++ Builder 10 Seattle NotificationCenter linker error

Tags: linker-errors, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-10-seattle

I've created a new VCL form using RAD Studio 10 Seattle.
I added a NotificationCenter at design time. Then I compiled it and ran it successfully.

But when I made the following two steps:
**1. Went to**

> Project -> Options -> C++ Linker

and unchecked the "Link with Dynamic RTL" option.

**2. Went to**

> Project -> Options -> Packages -> Runtime packages

and unchecked the "Link with runtime packages" option.

These options are unchecked in order to make the .exe standalone i.e. to be able to execute the .exe file without the IDE. So when these options are unchecked all libraries and packages are linked to the .exe file.

But now when I compile it, at link stage it gives me the following errors:

```
[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'SHStrDupW' referenced from D:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN64\RELEASE\RTL.A|System.Win.Notification.o
[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'WindowsDeleteString' referenced from D:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN64\RELEASE\RTL.A|Winapi.UI.Notifications.o
[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'RoInitialize' referenced from D:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN64\RELEASE\RTL.A|System.Win.WinRT.o
[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'RoUninitialize' referenced from D:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN64\RELEASE\RTL.A|System.Win.WinRT.o
[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'WindowsGetStringRawBuffer' referenced from D:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN64\RELEASE\RTL.A|System.Win.WinRT.o
[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'WindowsCreateString' referenced from D:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN64\RELEASE\RTL.A|System.Win.WinRT.o
[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'RoGetActivationFactory' referenced from D:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN64\RELEASE\RTL.A|System.Win.WinRT.o
[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'RoActivateInstance' referenced from D:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\17.0\LIB\WIN64\RELEASE\RTL.A|System.Win.WinRT.o
```

So I searched my

> Embarcadero/17.0/

directory for reference in the first linker error `SHStrDupW` and found three files with extenstion .h or .hpp and included them into my project, but the same results followed.

**Does anyone have idea how to fix this bug, I would appreciate all kind of help?** :)

P.S: It doesn't matter if I compile it for win32 or win64 OS.

Answer (score 1):

The linker errors are referring to Win32/WinRT API functions.  You need to add `Shlwapi.lib` and `runtimeobject.lib` to your project to resolve those references.

Comment: I added 
    `#include <Shlwapi.hpp>  
    #include <runtimeobject.hpp>`
But I can't seem to find the runtimeobject.hpp file. All I find is `runtimeobject.def` file. 

The results only with the first library is the same. @Remy Lebeau

Comment: `#include`'ing an `.hpp` file is not the same thing as linking to a `.lib` file.  As I said earlier, you need to add the `.lib` files to your project to resolve the linker errors.  The `.hpp` files merely declare the functions (and no, there is no `runtimeobject.hpp` file, use `Winstring.h` and `Roapi.h` instead), but the `.lib` files link to the DLLs that implement the functions.

Comment: Is there a DLL version of this file? If I compile using `runtimeobject.lib` it fails to run on windows7 `(regsvr32 mydll.dll fails - my code compiles to a DLL)`. I can write a runtime check for OS if a DLL version of it is available.

Comment: @SahilSingh regsvr32 is only used with COM DLLs, which yours is not

Comment: Yes, I am compiling a COM DLL, which is then used by some other project. regsvr32 is a necessary step.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you know if it is possible to do a LoadLibrary() at run time instead of statically linking with `runtimeobject.lib`

Comment: @SahilSingh: you didn't say before that it was a COM DLL. In that case, it fails because you are static linking to functions that simply do not exist on Windows 7. You would have to manually load (or delay-load) `api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll` directly. And since it has a version number in its filename, I would expect the filename to change over time, whereas `runtimeobject.lib` (and `windowsapp.lib`) would likely reference the latest filename across versions.